# Export excel file with password in SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: excel, sas, export

I have a table in SAS Enterprise Guide, I want to export the data to Excel File  with password. im trying to use VBscript but its doesnt work.
please help

This is the vbScript name  :

```
set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
object.visible=false
set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("D:\Acquisition.xlsx")
objWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\Acquisition_pss.xlsx",,"mypass"
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit**
```

And how i call the vbscript:

```
1. %sysexec cscript "D:\convert.vbs"
2. x "D:\convert.vbs"
```

this is the log :
 NOTE : WRITING TAGSETS.SASREPORT13(EGSR) Body file: EGSR

Comment: Please post any code you've tried, in particular, your VB script that isn't working would be helpful.

Comment: What profile is your EG session using ?

Comment: that is my code,

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://support.sas.com/kb/31/328.html